# Set datasource for a chuck item created using small dropdown box template in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

Set data source for a chuck item using small drop down box template in Sitecore
I couldn't see any data source field in this template, how I suppose to fill the drop down. I can add a single item by filling values in items fields

Comment: Have you tried setting `Items` field with values separated by pipe character `|`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak no, but I tried now and working :), is there any way to get this using a datasource item

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Small Drop Down Box` template uses `Items` field so you tried correctly.

If you want it to add more than 1 item, you should separate them using pipe character `|`.

From what I know there is no way of using a datasource item for that template.